# How to Regex this string?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get `string 1`, `string 2` and `string 3`, ... from below string:

```
...
BEGINID:"MyId":string 1,string 2,string 3, string ...,ENDID
...
```

*(`string 1`, `string 2` and `string 3`, ... don't contain charater `,`)*

Currently, my code is:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(givenString, "BEGINID:\"MyId\":(.*?)ENDID", RegexOptions.Singleline);
string output = m.Groups[1].Value;
```

then I split string `output` by `,` character.

I want when I regex, I can get all these string I need, without use split, some thing like this pattern:

```
BEGINID:\"MyId\":(([^,]*,?)*?)ENDID
```

But I don't know how to do next. Can you tell me? Thank.

**EDIT:** I just edit my string, so it is general string, not a HTML string.

Comment: Take a [tour here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) please

Comment: Next you should: use HtmlAgilityPack to parse HTML, read on XPath to find node you are looking for  and `String.Split` to split string on comma... Note that it is generally better to not show that you want to [parse HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/) in questions....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\G` assert position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

```
String input = @"<html>
...
<span id=""MyId"">string 1,string 2,string 3</span>
...
</html>";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?:<span id=""MyId"">|\G),?([^<>,]+)");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

**Output:**

```
string 1
string 2
string 3
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/4XrhUp)

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wT0zZ8/4)

Comment: It's my downvote, never recommend wrong tool. Regex is the wrong tool here. Refer comments below question.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel then why you fail to mark this question as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/ ?

Comment: That's not the duplicate, read the question again. Question is different but answer is always same. Duplicates should be marked based on duplicate questions not duplicate answers.

Comment: For some reason, I choose to use Regex here. I know some other way to do, example find the ID "MyId", then find next `>` and `<`. Thank for help, sir! I will edit my string to it not be html then people could easy to help me.

Comment: @TuyenTk Editing the input string may fool people, but it doesn't changes the fact. And that brings XY problem in to place. If you're happy to use regex, go ahead. but be aware of the fundamental problem.

Comment: @AvinashRaj it work perfectly, and now I learned a new Regex formula, thank.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I will work hard to avoid that problem. I'm quite new to c# and regex. Thank for warning me.